# Android Firebase Realtime database blog app

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a simple android firebase blog app

I want to create a new post in my Realtime database but only two attributes are saved in the database

Only the title and body attribute get sent into my Realtime database and the rest are missing and I see no error in my logcat

Post.java

```java
public class Post {

    SimpleDateFormat ISO_8601_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sss'Z'");


    private String title, body, uid, date;
    private int vote;


    Post() {
    }

    public Post(String title, String body, String uid) {

        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.uid = uid;
        date = ISO_8601_FORMAT.format(new Date());
        vote = 0;

    }

}
```

I want to call the addPost method in my PostActivity to send the data to firebase

PostActivity.java

```java
   private void addPost(String title, String body) {
      FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
      FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        Post post = new Post(title, body, mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());


        mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Posts").push().setValue(post)
                .addOnCompleteListener(c -> {
                    if (c.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(e -> Toast.makeText(this, "" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());


    }
```

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

Comment: Are you sure the user is logged in ? you can try adding `Log.d("TAG", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())` before calling the database code

Comment: Is the UID of the user also added to Firebase? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @Dharmaraj  yes the user is logged in, the app doesn't allow the user to access the postActivity if they are not logged, even when I remove the uid attribute is still only sends two things

Comment: Can you please try logging the new Post?

Comment: @Dharmaraj please advise on how to do it.

Comment: `Log.d("TAG", post.toString())`

Comment: @Dharmaraj it returns  com.example.app.Post@c19ab9e, I can also Log.d all the attributes with their getters, so everything seems to be working fine with the Post object

Comment: Can you just add a screenshot of data that is being added in the database? I am curios what's missing.

Comment: Based on the `Post` you shared, I expect no properties to be stored as nothing is public in that class. Same as Dharmaraj asked: can you edit your question to show what data is stored in the database for `setValue(post)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  find the screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOvgj.png

Comment: Hmmm...., and is this your entire `Post` class in the question? I'm asking because (afaik) Firebase only considers **public** fields/getters/setters when reading/writing custom classes.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, I simply needed to make the fields public

Comment: Good to hear.    I wrote an answer below explaining the logic that Firebase uses when determining what properties to read from/write to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase only considers fields, getters and setters that are public when reading/writing custom classes. Private fields, getters, and setters are not considered.

So the `Post` class in your question *should* result in no properties being read from/written to the database, as all fields are private. If you want them to be read/written, mark the fields public, or add public getters/setters for them.